# How can i create array of react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am creating Address Data fields where `country->state->city`  are created by using react-select.

All the data of `country->state->city` is coming through API. If is it single address then there is no issue.

But I want to add multiple address. I want `country->state->city` in each address.

So how can I differentiate the `country->state->city` from each address block.

How can I create array of `country->state->city` using react-select.

Comment: Are you  talking about Multi option.

Comment: no, I am not talking about the multi options. I want to create array of fields using react-select. for example I have one country[1] field with all the countries options now i want to create another country[2] field using react-select with same options. but the selectedOption may be different.

Comment: Im having a hard time comprehensing what you're talking about tbh

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the exact question, but will answer based on what I understood:

You can use map function, to map each address to a react-select component.
and then display the component in the JSX.

const address = ['ad1', 'ad2', 'ad3'] //can be different based on your apis, it could be objects with 'house number', 'address line 1' etc.

```js
const admap = address.map((add, index) => (
   <div key={index}>
     // put your react select stuff
   </div>
))
```

then you can use {address} in the JSX to display the selects for each address.